# Is there any use for live fish, and how can you keep them alive?

Tags: dont-starve

In Don't Starve, when you pull a fish from a pond, it flops for a few seconds, then dies.

Is there any purpose to the live fish?  Or is it merely window dressing animation?

If there is a use, what do you use to keep them alive?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the wiki states under Trivia it's just a fancy animation. The fish cannot be kept alive and there is no practical use to the live fish.

> When Fish is on the ground, it flops around, then perishes, its eyes becoming crossed out.

Comment: It actually doesn't say anything in the wiki specifically about it being JUST animation.  I'm accepting the answer because I believe this to be true, though.

Comment: @DavidM Usually stuff that shows up under Trivia is known to be only for decorative purpose and in very rare cases it interferes with